# knex.js casts null to NaN

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have an object:

```
var record = {
  foo: null,
  bar: 42
}
```

I want to insert one to the table:

```
console.log(db('foos_and_bars').insert(record).toString());
// insert into "foos_and_bars" ("foo", "bar") values ('NaN', 42)
```

My field allowed to be null, so I don't expect knex to perform such stuff.

What can be the reason of this? I've inserted null-s multiple times before and don't achieve such situations.

**UPD:** I've added `toString()` just to ensure how query looks like. With regular running I've - receive error:

> error: insert into "foos_and_bars" ("foo", "bar") values ($1, $2) - invalid input syntax for integer: "NaN"

Comment: a field of type nullable integer? why? I assume knex recognizes this field as numeric and tries to convert the null.

Comment: Here's a related [issue](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1276) on knex's github. What dialect are you using?

Comment: @Thomas yep field is nullable. I've insert null from postgres console and everything ok. I should do it cause I have extremely unreliable data provider and prefer having null in database instead of errors.

Comment: @dvlsg I'm using postgres. Do you know is there a way to insert null-s right now?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately. Looks like postgres [should be handling nulls](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/85403e8302cba5ef0895760212574808ad29787b/src/dialects/postgres/utils.js#L47-L49), unless I'm reading the wrong spot. Maybe try adding some logging / breakpoints / whatever to that function and see what's going on there?

Comment: I'd guess that something somewhere inside knex is blindly using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to get things ready for the database, I guess this because `parseInt(null)` is `NaN` and @dvslg's related issue suggests the knex's NULL has some holes. Maybe grep the source for `parseInt` calls and work backwards.

Comment: this is a bit of a roundabout way of doing this but an approach I've seen is to set the default on that column to null in the schema, then do a pass over the keys on an insert/update and delete any null values in the bindings. in that case it looks like knex doesn't consider undefined values and the db just falls back to the default.